# Mule ESB HTTP POST Request with URL-Form-Encoded Body

Tags: http, rest, mule, esb, http-post

I'm new in Mule ESB and trying to send a post request to a REST Service. The body of the request is in String form and the request should be x-www-form-urlencoded. I set the payload to my parameters and send the request to the REST Service but I get an exception:

```
Failed to invoke REST service "http://username:password@192.168.10.252/api/rest/session/login.json". Message payload is of type: String
```

My Rest URL is: (#[restURL]) ${dms.host}/api/rest/session/login.json

My parameter is (set as payload #[restBody]):  username=user&password=pass

```
<sub-flow name="RESTrequestToDMS" doc:name="RESTrequestToDMS" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <set-variable variableName="originalMessage" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Backup original message"/>
    <logger message="#[restBody]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="restHTTPmethod == 'POST'">
            <processor-chain>    
                <set-payload value="#[restBody]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>           
                <http:rest-service-component httpMethod="POST" serviceUrl="http://${dms.user}:${dms.pass}@#[restURL]"></http:rest-service-component>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <when expression="restHTTPmethod == 'GET'">
            <processor-chain>
                <http:rest-service-component httpMethod="GET" serviceUrl="http://${dms.user}:${dms.pass}@#[restURL]?#[restBody]"></http:rest-service-component>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <processor-chain>
                <logger message="Unknown http method type is provided! " level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <set-variable variableName="RESTResponse" value="#[payload]" doc:name="set RESTResponse"/>
    <set-payload value="#[flowVars['originalMessage']]" doc:name="Restore Original Message"/>
</sub-flow>
```

Can somebody help me figure this out please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Note: Updated according to David's reply.

**-------------------UPDATE--------------------**

So now, for testing purposes, I have modified the flow like this:

```
<set-payload value="#[restBody]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<custom-transformer class="de.mfg.osii.http.StringToURIParametersMapTransformer" doc:name="String To URI Parameters"/>  
<http:rest-service-component httpMethod="POST" serviceUrl="http://${dms.user}:${dms.pass}@#[restURL]">
    <http:requiredParameter key="username" value="#[payload.get('username')]" />
    <http:requiredParameter key="password" value="#[payload.get('password')]" />
</http:rest-service-component>
```

So now the payload is: {username=user, password=pass}
But now when I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
1. Failed to invoke REST service "http://user:pass@192.168.10.252/api/rest/session/login.json". Message payload is of type: LinkedHashMap (org.mule.transport.http.components.RestServiceException)
```

**Update:** The above problem, the exception, has just been solved by adding a message-property "Content-Type" with the value "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Still the last part, below, remains a mystery for me :)

The other thing is, as I stated in the comment to David's answer, can I add the required parameters for the rest component in an adaptive way? To be more clearer, I do not want to create different flows for every different request. I have the parameter map in the payload, so I want to iterate over them and put them in the required parameters. Is something like this possible?

Thanks a lot in advance!

**-------------------UPDATE--------------------**

So, I've modified my flow and used David's suggestions. However, now, I'm getting an HTTP 405 error (Method not allowed). But I'm sure I'm posting to the correct address with correct content-type. What is the reason for this? Does anybody have an idea?

My payload coming into this flow is a string (url encoded parameters) such as ->

sessionId=9eub9gm7k7oc1ub81dhef6t46q&xml=%3CObjectList%3E%3CFolderObject%3E%3CAddToFolder%20RefType%3D%22Path%22%20ClassName%3D%22FolderObject%22%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B%2FfolderPath%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FAddToFolder%3E%3CName%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5Baaa%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FName%3E%3CDescription%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5BRequests%20from%20user%20aaa%20are%20stored%20in%20this%20folder%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FDescription%3E%3CNoErrorIfExist%2F%3E%3C%2FFolderObject%3E%3C%2FObjectList%3E

```
<flow name="RESTrequestToDMS" doc:name="RESTrequestToDMS" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <set-variable variableName="originalMessage" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Backup original message"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="restHTTPmethod == 'POST'">
            <processor-chain>
                <set-payload value="#[restBody]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
                <logger message="The payload before http post is: #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <http:outbound-endpoint  exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP" address="http://#[restURL]"  user="${dms.user}" password="${dms.pass}" contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                </http:outbound-endpoint>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <when expression="restHTTPmethod == 'GET'">
            <processor-chain>
                <http:outbound-endpoint method="GET"  exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP" address="http://#[restURL]?#[restBody]"  user="${dms.user}" password="${dms.pass}" contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        </http:outbound-endpoint>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <processor-chain>
                <logger message="Unknown http method type is provided! " level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="payload != null &amp;&amp; payload != empty &amp;&amp; payload != ''">
            <processor-chain>
                <json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" returnClass="java.util.Map"/>
                <set-variable variableName="RESTResponse" value="#[payload]" doc:name="set RESTResponse"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <processor-chain>
                <logger message="The payload is null or empty! HTTP response code is: #[message.inboundProperties['http.status']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <set-variable variableName="RESTResponse" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status']]" doc:name="Set HTTP Status Code"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <set-payload value="#[flowVars['originalMessage']]" doc:name="Restore Original Message"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: I don't get the purpose of the `http:object-to-http-request-transformer` / `http:outbound-endpoint` pair at the beginning of the `sub-flow`. Also don't use the `echo-component` to log, use the `logger` message processor.

Comment: I actually dropped that line already but forgot to change here. Do you have any recommandation as a solution for this problem? This keeps annoying me and I couldn't find a solution to append a String body to my request.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Still, I don't get why there are still two outbound HTTP calls done in the subflow (one with `http:outbound-endpoint` and one with `http:rest-service-component`). Do you really want to call the remote service twice?

Comment: No, outbound component was my mistake. I'm actually only trying to call the REST service, but I couldn't figure out how exactly to do that. Calling the service for GET requests is fairly easy but I couldn't figure out how to do that for POST request with String body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you pass parameters to be URL encoded with the `rest-service-component`:

```
<http:rest-service-component httpMethod="POST"
    serviceUrl="http://${dms.user}:${dms.pass}@#[restURL]">
    <http:requiredParameter key="username" value="user" />
    <http:requiredParameter key="password" value="pass" />
</http:rest-service-component>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to make this adaptable to changing number of variables? I'm trying to implement this part as one subflow and send the parameters for all requests in URL. Is there an efficient way for this kind of problem?  I already have a Map of URI parameters. So now do I have to set these by requiredparameter option one by one? I see that I can not use foreach inside the component, thus I'm not sure have to map all of them at once.

Comment: Then the best is to use an outbound HTTP endpoint and build the URL yourself in a MEL component.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to build that URL with the parameter Map that I have, please? I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: `<set-payload value="#[restBody]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<http:outbound-endpoint method="POST" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP" address="http://#[restURL]"  user="${dms.user}" password="${dms.pass}" contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                    
</http:outbound-endpoint>`

This just worked. Thanks :)